# Buildr: How do I define a project which depends on another project in the same Buildfile?

Tags: scala, buildr

This seems like a simple task in Buildr, so I must be missing something obvious because I can't make it work.  Suppose I have a directory with two files, like so:

```
test/lib/src/main/scala/MyLib.scala
test/app/src/main/scala/MyApp.scala
```

`MyLib.scala` is:

```
class MyLib {
  def hello() { println("Hello!") }
}
```

And `MyApp.scala` is:

```
object MyApp extends App {
  val ml = new MyLib
  ml.hello()
}
```

Building these with `scalac` is straightforward:

```
$ cd test
$ scalac lib/src/main/scala/MyLib.scala -d target/main/classes
$ scalac app/src/main/scala/MyApp.scala -cp target/main/classes -d target/main/classes
$ cd target/main/classes/
$ scala MyApp
Hello!
```

However, my naïve attempt to turn this into a `Buildfile` (in the `test` folder):

```
require 'buildr/scala'

lib_layout = Layout.new
lib_layout[:source, :main, :scala] = 'lib/src/main/scala'
app_layout = Layout.new
app_layout[:source, :main, :scala] = 'app/src/main/scala'

define 'mylib', :layout => lib_layout do
end

define 'myapp', :layout => app_layout do
  compile.with project('mylib')
end
```

fails with:

```
(in /test, development)
Building mylib
Compiling myapp into /test/target/main/classes
/test/app/src/main/scala/MyApp.scala:2: error: not found: type MyLib
  val ml = new MyLib
               ^
one error found
Buildr aborted!
RuntimeError : Failed to compile, see errors above
```

and if I run `buildr --trace` it's pretty clear that the reason `scalac` is failing is because the classpath does not include `target/main/classes`.

How do I make this happen?  I know that separating the two projects may seem contrived, but I have something much more sophisticated in mind, and this example boiled the problem down to its essential components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idiomatic way to describe your project with Buildr would be to use sub-projects,

Note: `buildfile` below goes into the `test/` directory.

```
require 'buildr/scala'

define "my-project" do
  define "lib" do
  end

  define "app" do
    compile.with project("lib").compile.target
  end
end
```

The two sub-projects `lib` and `app` are automatically mapped to the `lib/` and `app/` sub-directories and Buildr will automatically look for sources under `src/main/scala` for each.

Comment: As another newbie, I found that `compile.with projects('lib')` works too. Is there a difference?

Answer (score 0):

Buildr common convention for project layout looks for compiled classes in `target/classes` and `target/test/classes`.  I see your build is placing classes into `target/main/classes`:

So you'll want to change your scala params to the expected location, or change the layout to include:

```
lib_layout[:target, :main, :scala] = 'target/main/classes'
```

If you also need to change the layout for test classes (I'm guessing you don't), use:

```
lib_layout[:target, :test, :scala] = ...
```